# Por que usar uma coluna de uma tabela virtual torna uma SQL no Oracle lenta

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, oracle11g

Boas.

Sem querer deixar o assunto muito "gasoso" mas queria apenas dicas de coisas a investigar no ambiente.

Tenho uma SQL que usa uma tabela virtual , por uma série de motivos que não vem muito ao caso.

Algo como :

```
select *
from
(select a,b,c,x,virtual.d
 from tabela1,
(select a,b,c,d
 from tabela2
 where ....) virtual
where virtual.a = tabela1.a
and virtual.b = tabela1.b
virtual.c = tabela1.c)
```

A SQL executa rápido , mas preciso fazer um teste do tipo

```
 select *
    from
    (select a,b,c,virtual.d
     from tabela1,
    (select a,b,c,d
     from tabela2
     where ....) virtual
    where virtual.a = tabela1.a
    and virtual.b = tabela1.b
    virtual.c = tabela1.c)
where ((c <> d) or (a=1))
```

Ao fazer isto a SQL fica extremamente lenta.

O que poderia ser investigado.

Não sei se detalhes do tipo descrição , índices etc ajudariam, a questão básica é :

**Por que usar uma coluna de uma tabela virtual torna uma SQL no Oracle lenta ?**

Grato.

Answer (score 2):

Caso interesse a outrem , resolvi com um *HINT*

```
SELECT /*+USE_CONCAT*/ * from
    (select a,b,c,virtual.d
     from tabela1,
    (select a,b,c,d
     from tabela2
     where ....) virtual
    where virtual.a = tabela1.a
    and virtual.b = tabela1.b
    virtual.c = tabela1.c)
where ((c <> d) or (a=1))
```

[Fonte](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#6873)